# Android - when I click on REFRESH button it always goes to onFailure

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I'm trying to create a Mancala game. I'm doing a Wifi-Direct, but everytime I'm clicking on REFRESH button, it goes to onFailure method.
The purpose of the refresh button is to discover new devices near me, but unrotuantely I can't find any devices because it's going to onFailure method.

What can I do?

```
public class wifiLoginScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WifiP2pManager mWifiP2pManager;
    private WifiP2pManager.Channel mWifiP2pChannel;
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    private boolean mWifiDirectEnabled;
    private List<String> mPeersList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mPeersAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi_login_screen);

        // Initialize WifiP2pManager and WifiP2pManager.Channel objects
        mWifiP2pManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mWifiP2pChannel = mWifiP2pManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

        // Initialize the BroadcastReceiver to listen for Wi-Fi Direct events
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
                    // Wi-Fi Direct state has changed
                    int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
                    mWifiDirectEnabled = (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED);
                } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
                    // The list of available peers has changed
                    mWifiP2pManager.requestPeers(mWifiP2pChannel, new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {
                            // Filter the list of available peers to only show the ones that have the same Wi-Fi network name as the device
                            String ssid = getCurrentSsid(wifiLoginScreen.this);
                            mPeersList.clear();
                            for (WifiP2pDevice device : peers.getDeviceList()) {
                                if (device.deviceName.contains(ssid)) {
                                    mPeersList.add(device.deviceName);
                                }
                            }
                            mPeersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };

        // Register the BroadcastReceiver to listen for Wi-Fi Direct events
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);

        // Initialize the list view to show the available peers
        ListView peersListView = findViewById(R.id.peersListView);
        mPeersAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mPeersList);
        peersListView.setAdapter(mPeersAdapter);
        // Initialize the "Refresh" button to trigger a new search for available peers
        Button refreshButton = findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);
        refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mWifiDirectEnabled) {
                    mWifiP2pManager.discoverPeers(mWifiP2pChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            // Discovery initiated successfully
                            Toast.makeText(wifiLoginScreen.this, "Searching for available devices...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int reason) {
                            // Discovery failed to start
                            Toast.makeText(wifiLoginScreen.this, "Failed to start discovery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(wifiLoginScreen.this, "Wi-Fi Direct is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Register the BroadcastReceiver to listen for Wi-Fi Direct events
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Unregister the BroadcastReceiver
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    // Helper method to get the current Wi-Fi network name
    public static String getCurrentSsid(Context context) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        if (ssid.startsWith("\"") && ssid.endsWith("\"")) {
            ssid = ssid.substring(1, ssid.length() - 1);
        }
        return ssid;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you declare all necessary permissions in your manifest and did you also request them using `requestPermissions`?

Comment: Yes, I did...☹️

Comment: What does logcat say? Please show us all errors when clicking on the button. Please be aware there might be errors coming from the system and not tagged with your package name.